# Why program not returning binary numbers in Text.txt as it's copying binary numbers from Image.jpeg

Tags: java

Read operation reading Source in Binary format,but write operation not Writing it in such a manner.

```
try
{
    FileInputStream fr=new FileInputStream("Image.jpeg");
    FileOutputStream fr1=new FileOutputStream("Text.txt");
    int temp=0;
    while((temp=fr.read())!=-1)
    {                       
        fr1.write(temp);                        
    }
    fr1.close();
    fr.close();             
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

Comment: So you want binary copy Image.jpeg to Text.txt ?

Comment: but if you open text.txt, you will see garbage trying to look characters

Comment: What output are you getting?  What are you expecting to get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it could be because you are reading data from "Image.jpeg" and not "Desert.jpeg". It could also be that you are writing to "Text.txt" and not "text.txt". I could also be that you are copying the jpeg image data byte for byte, and that will be interpreted as text by your text editing program, rather than as 'binary' as you suggest.

What I really want to know is, what did you expect to see in the text file?

**Edit:** Now that I know you wanted the human-readable binary, try this:

```
try
{
    FileInputStream fr=new FileInputStream("Image.jpeg");
    FileOutputStream fr1=new FileOutputStream("Text.txt");
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(fr1);
    int temp=0;
    while((temp=fr.read())!=-1)
    {                       
        out.write(Integer.toBinaryString(temp) + " ");
    }
    out.close();
    fr1.close();
    fr.close();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

Comment: I am expecting output in binary numbers,as read operation reading Image.jpeg in binary format.
#Corrections

Comment: Does that mean you want to see binary numbers written in a binary format like 010011101? Because all numbers are binary in a sense, as our decimal numbers are represented as binary under the hood. If that is the case, you should consider using the [String.toBinaryString(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toBinaryString(int)) function.

Comment: I am guessing that output should be in format of 100011011,but i am getting gabage values in output file.
This is"Ðàé^/?µÉf€wõÿ ˆøŒ¡õë™ÈBºŠ¡Î˜ðªÌ[²¤ö/‚@"what i am getting and output file size is similar to source file.

Comment: That is because your literal byte for byte copy will be interpreted as text. The data in an image can be really anything, so if you were to get a big table of Unicode characters and put your finger down on a random cell you're going to find yourself picking a whole lot of 'garbage' characters.

Comment: Also check out my edits

Comment: Thanks really appreciate your help.
Just one correction
out.write(Integer.toBinaryString(temp) + " ");
As temp is declared as int.
Thanks once again.

Comment: Oops! Looks like someone corrected it for me though. Glad to help!